# (deep learning) Is there a type of layer that can reverse the max-pooling operation?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, autoencoders

As far as I know, we have deconvolutional layer to reverse the convolutional layer. Is there something like that for max-pooling?

Also, I want to add this reverse max-pooling into an autoencoder, is there any existing example of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Zeiler says in his paper "Visualizing and Understanding Convolutional Networks" :

"In the convnet, the max pooling operation is non-invertible, however we can obtain an approximate inverse by recording the locations of the maxima within each pooling region in a set of switch variables."

Check up the Zeiler's paper in the Unpooling section.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked this paper [Stacked Convolutional Auto-Encoders for Hierarchical Feature Extraction](http://people.idsia.ch/~ciresan/data/icann2011.pdf)?

> Here we introduce a max-pooling layer that introduces sparsity over the hidden
>   representation by erasing all non-maximal values in non overlapping subregions.

Basically it's the same as alviur's answer. Since they used only one max pooling layer, instead of actually doing the down-sampling for each box, they just erased all the non-maximal values, and the sparse representation is used for reconstruction.

Answer (score 0):

MaxPool is not generally invertible, but PyTorch for example provides a function which computes a *pseudo*-inverse, where all elements other than the max are set to `0`:

> [`MaxUnpool2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MaxUnpool2d.html) takes in as input the output of `MaxPool2d` including the indices of the maximal values and computes a partial inverse in which all non-maximal values are set to zero.